# How to show a segmented control and multiselect buttongroup at top of a list

Tags: gui-design, controls

I'm struggling on how I can present the following to my users and that they understand how it works:

In a desktop app, we have a 'Recent' phonecalls list. This list shows all calls that came in and went out. A user is able to see just his own phonecalls or choose to see all calls that came in or went out for his team. So i solved this by adding a segmented control.

But the list shows two phonelines that come in, and he has to be able to choose whether he wants to see the phonecalls of the one line or the other line or just both.

I solved it like this for now, but i dont think its really clear to the user that the one thing is toggle and the other is multiselect...

Or am i just making it really hard for myself?

Appriciate the help!

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Does one person use multiple lines? Do people share lines? Are there fixed user-accounts that can be logged in to different phones, like a flex office? The right UI is highly dependent on the use case; why are you filtering by person and by line?

Answer (score 0):

I also think that the current UI might be confusing for users, because the visuals for My calls/ Team calls on one hand and Phonelines on the other hand are really similar, but they behave differently.

"My calls" and "Team calls" act like filters on the total number of calls. You could make this clear for the user by adding "filter" as a microcopy and using checkboxes next to each type.

By default, they would be both checked, and the user could uncheck either to select only one set of calls.

The design would also be sufficiently different from Phoneline 1 or 2, and it would reduce the risk of confusion.

Comment: Hi Celinelenoble, thanks a lot for your answer, really appriciate it. I agree the current UI is most likely confusing for users. Adding a bit of copy and checkboxes does make more sense. I think i was trying to avoid using checkboxes, because i think the multiselect buttongroup looks and works a bit nicer. But in this combination it just makes it confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You might be adding too many controls on this screen. Consider showing this option under the app's setting tab, or under a setting icon in the Recent screen.

The option could be "Group calls by phone number" and the recent call list could load in an accordion format, splitting the entire call log by phone number instead of dates & time.

Ask yourself how many times "browsing for a specific phone number" will be used. Realistically how many users are toggling to view by all or by specific phone number constantly?

Answer (score 0):

## Give an 'All' or 'Any' option on the controls, and you can use two segmented controls.

Since you have a small number of lines (2 it seems), you can use 2 of the same controls. Have the default be All, and let the user toggle as needed.

Is there a reason you have them on two separate levels? You could put them at the same level above the results, below the title:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the UI is confusing because you're using two very similar controls for two very different behaviors. If you stick to the classic checkbox instead of the toggle for line selection it should be clear enough:
[image]